# How to mark packets sending to server using iptables extensions?

Tags: header, debian, iptables, packets

I'd like to make SSH-identification a little stronger using iptables extensions (or IPSec tools?) **for marking (while sending) and matching (while recieving) the packets** between my laptop and my server.

I need no VPN, just to send additional information in IP Options header (or in the AH field?).. while talking to server.

It would be nice if it could be possible **by using iptables plugins for Debian only** (to first alter the headers and then compare the key inside on my remote host).

*I googled for a day and found such topics as Inspect protocols AH and ESP for content; Using iptables string-matching filter; Payload mangling etc - but for a now I could not understand the most important thing: which packet to install for Debian on both computers:)*

My dream is to block connections using iptables on port 22 (which have no signature inside) before the SSH handshake starts. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

I did my homework again, and gurus online told me to use the ToS field, "which remains the same while being transmitted over global networks".

An example how to set it:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p TCP --dport 22 -j TOS --set-tos 0x10
```

*And it's a very small field (256 bits), filled up with the service information, so there is no much room to play with and you must be very careful. But still!..*

Later then the ToS value can be read on the receiving machine using something like

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tos --tos 0x16
```